# Self-deleting PowerShell script deletes all contents but not the containing/parent folder

Tags: windows, powershell, directory, self-destruction

I'm trying to have the PowerShell 5.1 script self-delete itself, along with the entire folder contents (including subfolders).  I'm using the below code, which works to a point.  It does delete all of the folder's contents (including the PowerShell script), but it does **NOT** delete the folder itself.

#### `script.ps1`:

```
# Main code

# At end of script
Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe /c rmdir `"C:\test`" /s /q"
```

After running the above code, `C:\test` still exists, but empty.  How can I have the script also remove folder too?

#### Aditional Note

I've also tried using `Remove-Item -Path "C:\test" -Force -Recurse` at the end of the script, but it produces the following error:
`Remove-Item : Cannot remove the item at 'C:\test' because it is in use.`

I discovered that it's a [known issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/199921/force-remove-files-and-directories-in-powershell-fails-sometimes-but-not-always) when `Remove-Item` is used to delete the script itself.

Comment: Make sure the current working directory of both powershell and cmd is something other than `C:\test` before trying to remove it.

Comment: @dxiv How would I do that?  I added `Set-Location -Path "C:\"` and modified the `Invoke-Expression` to ``"cmd.exe /c `"cd c: & rmdir C:\test /s /q`""``, but it doesn't delete the folder still.

Comment: Make that `cd "C:\"` with a trailing `"\"` to change directories to the root. Without it, `cd C:` will just display the current directory on drive `C:`.

Comment: @dxiv I forgot the trailing ``\``.  But even adding that did not delete the folder.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution.  I experimented with using `Start-Process` instead, which creates a separate process altogether.  I also discovered not to use `-NoNewWindow` switch with it, otherwise I got the same results as with `Invoke-Expression`.

The following code works, deleting the entire folder contents and the folder itself:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c `"cd c:\ & rmdir C:\test /s /q`""
```

Comment: As a bonus, if you have spaces in the self-deleting script's parent folder (use `""` to escape double quotes), and want to programatically identify the parent folder, here is the command: ``Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c `"cd c:\ & rmdir ""$(Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)"" /s /q`""``

Comment: If you want to be extra cool, you can replace `Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` with `$PSScriptRoot`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the file `script.ps1` is located in the path `c:\test` which should be deleted - so as long as the script is running the folder is in use. I would therefore create a PowerShell job at the very end of the script which waits some seconds and thereafter delete that folder.

```
Start-Job -Name RemoveFolder -ScriptBlock {Start-Sleep 2;Remove-Item -LiteralPath 'C:\test' -Force -Recurse}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work either.  Since the job is using `Remove-Item`, and the folder is still in use, it probably runs into the known issue I linked to in my original post.